# Is there any way to refresh an embed as if the user has sent the command again after 3 seconds in discord.js?

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

I am actually working on a discord.js music bot and I want to the progress bar to edit after every 3 seconds until the song ends so is there any way to do that?
I have searched about this all over the internet but didn't found any answers..

my code:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: 'nowplaying',
    aliases: ['np'],
    category: 'Music',
    utilisation: '{prefix}nowplaying',

    execute(client, message) {
        if (!message.member.voice.channel) return message.channel.send(`${client.emotes.error} - You're not in a voice channel !`);

        if (message.guild.me.voice.channel && message.member.voice.channel.id !== message.guild.me.voice.channel.id) return message.channel.send(`${client.emotes.error} - You are not in the same voice channel !`);

        if (!client.player.getQueue(message)) return message.channel.send(`${client.emotes.error} - No music currently playing !`);

        const track = client.player.nowPlaying(message);
        const filters = [];

        Object.keys(client.player.getQueue(message).filters).forEach((filterName) => client.player.getQueue(message).filters[filterName]) ? filters.push(filterName) : false;

        message.channel.send({
            embed: {
                color: 'RED',
                author: { name: track.title },
                footer: { text: 'Developed by Haruke#6969' },
                fields: [
                    { name: 'Channel', value: track.author, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Requested by', value: track.requestedBy.username, inline: true },
                    { name: 'From playlist', value: track.fromPlaylist ? 'Yes' : 'No', inline: true },

                    { name: 'Views', value: track.views, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Duration', value: track.duration, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Filters activated', value: filters.length + '/' + client.filters.length, inline: true },

                    { name: 'Volume', value: client.player.getQueue(message).volume, inline: true },
                    { name: 'Repeat mode', value: client.player.getQueue(message).repeatMode ? 'Yes' : 'No', inline: true },
                    { name: 'Currently paused', value: client.player.getQueue(message).paused ? 'Yes' : 'No', inline: true },

                    { name: 'Progress bar', value: client.player.createProgressBar(message, { timecodes: true }), inline: true }
                ],
                thumbnail: { url: track.thumbnail },
                timestamp: new Date(),
            },
        });
    },
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.then` and `setInterval`. You just need to continuously edit the embed every 3 seconds. Then remove the interval once the song ended.

```js
let interval;
message.channel.send(/*...*/).then(m => {
interval = setInterval(() => {
if(!client.getQueue(m)) return clearInterval(interval);
m.edit(/*...*/)
        
        }, 3000)
})
```

Replace the `/*...*/` with your send data (the `{embed: {...}}`)

Comment: Sorry for terrible formatting. Please fix if you can

Answer (score 1):

I can't rewrite your code completely without seeing more of the code, but try using a while loop and using the difference between the current time and the time the song started to check if the song is over, and edit embed every three seconds until it's over.

```js
// ... the rest of your code above

const sleep = (milliseconds) => {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, milliseconds))
}

let songDuration = // whatever you'd use get song duration in seconds
let startTimestamp = Date.now()

while ((Date.now() - startTimestamp) / 1000 < songDuration) {
    // your code to edit the embed
    await sleep(3000) // make sure this executes async!
}
```